# Facing error while updating application on the MobileFirst Application Center

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

Facing an update error when uploading the ipa file of the iOS
application in order to update it on the Application Center of MFP.

There is a version 1.3 of the iOS application already uploaded on the
Application Center. Then built a new version 1.3.1 of the application
and created the ipa file. Opened the application on the Application
Center and selected the ipa file of the new version 1.3.1 from new file,
and then the following error occurred when Apply button is pressed.

"Cannot update application file: package and/or version are not
identical."

The identification information of the application is not changed.

What is the procedure to update the application with a new
version? Or, is it required to add the application as another application
every time they create a new version of the application?

Answer (score 0):

If the app names/ package name is identical then it can be added as
a new application and since the version is different and same
application, it will be added under the same app with different version
numbers. The screenshots of the steps are attached. Please follow the same
steps to add new version of the same package name.

In essence, you need to upload the app in the main page by add application
and not by going into the app and adding the application as this is only
for making changes in the updated app by rewriting it and not adding a
newer version. So the issue will be solved if you upload the app same way shown in the screenshots.

[image: Add Application]

[image]

Click on next and it will autofill the important details and give a description and add other optional functionalities and click submit.

[image]

If the package name is same, for example in the above sample all the package name has HybridEventSource in android. This is same in iOS apps too.